# How to implement Error bar in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am new to `iOS` programming and taking course work.

One of the homework talks about implementing an error bar which shows up when there is no network.

[image]

It also says not to use `UIAlertView`.

Can someone point me to resources how to do such a thing? I don't even know what to search.  I tried `implementing error bar` and alike queries which did not produce any useful result.

Comment: Did you just think about the problem and how you might solve it rather than just trying to search? What did you come up with?

Comment: it is a custom view -- for ready made code I'd suggest cocoacontrols

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom view and you won't find any of these in Xcode by default. You can implement it by yourself - but of course it needs some time and knowledge. Or you can get any ready made solution.

I found something called [`CWStatusBarNotification`](https://github.com/cezarywojcik/CWStatusBarNotification) and I know it's not the same but it's a good way to start.

Try searching in [**CocoaPods**](http://cocoapods.org). You can find many good libraries there with a documentations, tutorials etc.